# Was this video about a person who can withstand electricity staged?

Tags: physiology

This video, which is apparently by History.com Channel, shows a man called "Electric Mohan" from Kerala, India who doesn't get harmed when electricity flows through him.

Is it possible for any human being to withstand electricity of 3 Ampere, 220 Volts?
Is the person (or the video) doing some trick?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWNc2rYUT0c

Comment: The video is "blocked in my country" ( USA). Can you give a citation for the original source? A random YouTube video is not a notable claim.

Comment: nomenagentis is right that this is a duplicate of that; but I'm not allowed to vote to close this as a duplicate, because that doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer.

Comment: According to [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux#comment488365_166724) not being able to close as duplicate is a feature not a bug, i.e. this question should be allowed because the earlier question isn't helplful.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill If you [Google for 'Electric Mohan'](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Electric+Mohan) there are a lot of search results (some of which [e.g. this one](http://parasci.net/1164) repeat the claim as if they believe it true).

Comment: @Oddthinking I'm confused? This has been closed as a duplicate because it's been asked before and has an answer, but the duplicate mentioned doesn't have an answer? Also it seems like several comments have been deleted, but other comments referencing or answering these deleted comments have been left. Is this just to confuse people intentionally?

Comment: @superphonic: "This has been closed as a duplicate because it's been asked before and has an answer". No. This has been closed as a duplicate because it has been asked before, and the existing question covers this one well, and is highly upvoted, so there is no value in having both questions open.

Comment: Two comments have been deleted by the original commenter. No comments have been flagged by the community or touched by mods. Suggesting it is a deliberate attempt to confuse isn't helping; where you lack evidence, please assume good intentions over nefarious plans.